# Nested Resource Namespaced Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces

I built an app without namespaces and now want to try to learn namespaces.
As an example separating the app api and backend

Trying to get this result
/backend/directorycategory/1/directorylisting

I've removed the backend_ in certain places to try and debug as I suspect it has something to do with the fact that directorylisting is nested and has no backend infront of it like directory categories.

controller/backend/directorylistings_controller.rb

```
class Backend::DirectorylistingsController < ApplicationController
    # SECURITY
    before_action :set_backend_directorylisting, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

    # INDEX
    def index
    backend_directorycategory = Backend::Directorycategory.find(params[:directorycategory_id])
    @backend_directorylistings = backend_directorycategory.backend_directorylistings
    end

    # SHOW
    def show
        backend_directorycategory = Backend::Directorycategory.find(params[:directorycategory_id])
        @backend_directorycategory = backend_directorycategory.backend_directorylistings.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        backend_directorycategory = Backend::Directorycategory.find(params[:directorycategory_id])
        @directorylisting = backend_directorycategory.directorylistings.build
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # new.html.erb
            format.xml  { render :xml => @backend_directorycategory }
        end
    end

    # EDIT
    def edit
        backend_directorycategory = Backend::Directorycategory.find(params[:directorycategory_id])
        @directorylisting = backend_directorycategory.directorylistings.find(params[:id])
    end

    # CREATE
    def create
        @backend_directorycategory = Backend::Directorycategory.find(params[:directorycategory_id])
        @directorylisting = @backend_directorycategory.directorylistings.create(directorylisting_params)
        respond_to do |format|
        if @directorylisting.save
            format.html { redirect_to backend_directorycategory_directorylistings_path, notice: 'Directory Listing was Successfully Created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @directorylisting }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
                format.json { render json: @backend_directorylisting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # UPDATE
    def update
        respond_to do |format|
        if @directorylisting.update(directorylisting_params)
            format.html { redirect_to backend_directorycategory_directorylistings_path, notice: 'Directory Listing was Successfully Updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'edit' }
                format.json { render json: @directorylisting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # DELETE
    def destroy
        @backend_directorycategory = Directorycategory.find(params[:directorycategory_id])
        @directorylisting = @backend_directorycategory.directorylistings.find(params[:id])
        @directorylisting.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to backend_directorycategory_directorylistings_path, notice: 'Directory Listing was Successfully Deleted.'  }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end

    private

  def set_backend_directorylisting
        @directorylisting = Directorylisting.find(params[:id])
    end

  def directorylisting_backend_params
    params.require(:backend_directorylisting).permit(:memberlisting_id, :directorycategory_id)
    end

end
```

models/backend/directorylisting.rb

```
class Backend::Directorylisting < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Model Relationship
  belongs_to :backend_directorycategory
  belongs_to :backend_memberlisting
  has_one :backend_membercontact, :through => :backend_memberlisting

    # Validation for Form Fields (More of a Self-Check)
    validates :memberlisting_id, 
        presence: true

    # Validation for Form Fields (More of a Self-Check)
    validates :directorycategory_id, 
        presence: true

end
```

/models/backend.rb

```
module Backend
    def self.table_name_prefix
        'backend_'
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
# Active Security + Data Separation
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    # Security + Data Separation

    namespace :api do
            resources :directorycategories, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
                resources :directorylistings
            end
    end

  namespace :backend do
            # Member Routes
            resources :membercontacts do
                resources :memberlistings
            end

            # Directory Information
            resources :directorycategories do
                resources :directorylistings
            end
        end 

    # Mount Engine @ Root

end
```

Rake route (namespaced)

```
Prefix                                      Verb   URI                                                                                 Pattern                                                                      Controller#Action
api_directorycategory_directorylistings     GET    /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings(.:format)              api/directorylistings#index {:format=>"json"}
                                            POST   /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings(.:format)              api/directorylistings#create {:format=>"json"}
new_api_directorycategory_directorylisting  GET    /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/new(.:format)          api/directorylistings#new {:format=>"json"}
edit_api_directorycategory_directorylisting GET    /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id/edit(.:format)     api/directorylistings#edit {:format=>"json"}
api_directorycategory_directorylisting      GET    /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)          api/directorylistings#show {:format=>"json"}
                                            PATCH  /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)          api/directorylistings#update {:format=>"json"}
                                            PUT    /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)          api/directorylistings#update {:format=>"json"}
                                            DELETE /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)          api/directorylistings#destroy {:format=>"json"}
api_directorycategories                     GET    /api/directorycategories(.:format)                                                      api/directorycategories#index {:format=>"json"}
                                            POST   /api/directorycategories(.:format)                                                      api/directorycategories#create {:format=>"json"}
new_api_directorycategory                   GET    /api/directorycategories/new(.:format)                                                  api/directorycategories#new {:format=>"json"}
edit_api_directorycategory                  GET    /api/directorycategories/:id/edit(.:format)                                             api/directorycategories#edit {:format=>"json"}
api_directorycategory                       GET    /api/directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                                  api/directorycategories#show {:format=>"json"}
                                            PATCH  /api/directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                                  api/directorycategories#update {:format=>"json"}
                                            PUT    /api/directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                                  api/directorycategories#update {:format=>"json"}
                                            DELETE /api/directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                                  api/directorycategories#destroy {:format=>"json"}
backend_membercontact_memberlistings        GET    /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings(.:format)                      backend/memberlistings#index
                                            POST   /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings(.:format)                      backend/memberlistings#create
new_backend_membercontact_memberlisting     GET    /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/new(.:format)                  backend/memberlistings#new
edit_backend_membercontact_memberlisting    GET    /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id/edit(.:format)             backend/memberlistings#edit
backend_membercontact_memberlisting         GET    /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)                  backend/memberlistings#show
                                            PATCH  /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)                  backend/memberlistings#update
                                            PUT    /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)                  backend/memberlistings#update
                                            DELETE /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)                  backend/memberlistings#destroy
backend_membercontacts                      GET    /backend/membercontacts(.:format)                                                       backend/membercontacts#index
                                            POST   /backend/membercontacts(.:format)                                                       backend/membercontacts#create
new_backend_membercontact                   GET    /backend/membercontacts/new(.:format)                                                   backend/membercontacts#new
edit_backend_membercontact                  GET    /backend/membercontacts/:id/edit(.:format)                                              backend/membercontacts#edit
backend_membercontact                       GET    /backend/membercontacts/:id(.:format)                                                   backend/membercontacts#show
                                            PATCH  /backend/membercontacts/:id(.:format)                                                   backend/membercontacts#update
                                            PUT    /backend/membercontacts/:id(.:format)                                                   backend/membercontacts#update
                                            DELETE /backend/membercontacts/:id(.:format)                                                   backend/membercontacts#destroy
backend_directorycategory_directorylistings GET    /backend/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings(.:format)          backend/directorylistings#index
                                            POST   /backend/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings(.:format)          backend/directorylistings#create
new_backend_directorycategory_directorylisting  GET    /backend/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/new(.:format)      backend/directorylistings#new
edit_backend_directorycategory_directorylisting GET    /backend/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id/edit(.:format) backend/directorylistings#edit
backend_directorycategory_directorylisting  GET    /backend/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)      backend/directorylistings#show
                                            PATCH  /backend/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)      backend/directorylistings#update
                                            PUT    /backend/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)      backend/directorylistings#update
                                            DELETE /backend/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)      backend/directorylistings#destroy
backend_directorycategories                 GET    /backend/directorycategories(.:format)                                                  backend/directorycategories#index
                                            POST   /backend/directorycategories(.:format)                                                  backend/directorycategories#create
new_backend_directorycategory               GET    /backend/directorycategories/new(.:format)                                              backend/directorycategories#new
edit_backend_directorycategory              GET    /backend/directorycategories/:id/edit(.:format)                                         backend/directorycategories#edit
backend_directorycategory                   GET    /backend/directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                              backend/directorycategories#show
                                            PATCH  /backend/directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                              backend/directorycategories#update
                                            PUT    /backend/directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                              backend/directorycategories#update
                                            DELETE /backend/directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                              backend/directorycategories#destroy
```

rake route (:module)

```
Prefix                                      Verb   URI                                                                                 Pattern                                                                      Controller#Action
api_directorycategory_directorylistings     GET    /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings(.:format)              api/directorylistings#index {:format=>"json"}
                                            POST   /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings(.:format)              api/directorylistings#create {:format=>"json"}
new_api_directorycategory_directorylisting  GET    /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/new(.:format)          api/directorylistings#new {:format=>"json"}
edit_api_directorycategory_directorylisting GET    /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id/edit(.:format)     api/directorylistings#edit {:format=>"json"}
api_directorycategory_directorylisting      GET    /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)          api/directorylistings#show {:format=>"json"}
                                            PATCH  /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)          api/directorylistings#update {:format=>"json"}
                                            PUT    /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)          api/directorylistings#update {:format=>"json"}
                                            DELETE /api/directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)          api/directorylistings#destroy {:format=>"json"}
api_directorycategories                     GET    /api/directorycategories(.:format)                                                      api/directorycategories#index {:format=>"json"}
                                            POST   /api/directorycategories(.:format)                                                      api/directorycategories#create {:format=>"json"}
new_api_directorycategory                   GET    /api/directorycategories/new(.:format)                                                  api/directorycategories#new {:format=>"json"}
edit_api_directorycategory                  GET    /api/directorycategories/:id/edit(.:format)                                             api/directorycategories#edit {:format=>"json"}
api_directorycategory                       GET    /api/directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                                  api/directorycategories#show {:format=>"json"}
                                            PATCH  /api/directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                                  api/directorycategories#update {:format=>"json"}
                                            PUT    /api/directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                                  api/directorycategories#update {:format=>"json"}
                                            DELETE /api/directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                                  api/directorycategories#destroy {:format=>"json"}
membercontact_memberlistings        GET    membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings(.:format)                      backend/memberlistings#index
                                            POST   membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings(.:format)                      backend/memberlistings#create
new_membercontact_memberlisting     GET    membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/new(.:format)                  backend/memberlistings#new
edit_membercontact_memberlisting    GET    membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id/edit(.:format)             backend/memberlistings#edit
membercontact_memberlisting         GET    membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)                  backend/memberlistings#show
                                            PATCH  membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)                  backend/memberlistings#update
                                            PUT    membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)                  backend/memberlistings#update
                                            DELETE membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)                  backend/memberlistings#destroy
membercontacts                      GET    membercontacts(.:format)                                                       backend/membercontacts#index
                                            POST   membercontacts(.:format)                                                       backend/membercontacts#create
new_membercontact                   GET    membercontacts/new(.:format)                                                   backend/membercontacts#new
edit_membercontact                  GET    membercontacts/:id/edit(.:format)                                              backend/membercontacts#edit
membercontact                       GET    membercontacts/:id(.:format)                                                   backend/membercontacts#show
                                            PATCH  membercontacts/:id(.:format)                                                   backend/membercontacts#update
                                            PUT    membercontacts/:id(.:format)                                                   backend/membercontacts#update
                                            DELETE membercontacts/:id(.:format)                                                   backend/membercontacts#destroy
directorycategory_directorylistings GET    directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings(.:format)          backend/directorylistings#index
                                            POST   directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings(.:format)          backend/directorylistings#create
new_directorycategory_directorylisting  GET    directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/new(.:format)      backend/directorylistings#new
edit_directorycategory_directorylisting GET    directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id/edit(.:format) backend/directorylistings#edit
directorycategory_directorylisting  GET    directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)      backend/directorylistings#show
                                            PATCH  directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)      backend/directorylistings#update
                                            PUT    directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)      backend/directorylistings#update
                                            DELETE directorycategories/:directorycategory_id/directorylistings/:id(.:format)      backend/directorylistings#destroy
directorycategories                 GET    directorycategories(.:format)                                                  backend/directorycategories#index
                                            POST   directorycategories(.:format)                                                  backend/directorycategories#create
new_directorycategory               GET    directorycategories/new(.:format)                                              backend/directorycategories#new
edit_directorycategory              GET    directorycategories/:id/edit(.:format)                                         backend/directorycategories#edit
directorycategory                   GET    directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                              backend/directorycategories#show
                                            PATCH  directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                              backend/directorycategories#update
                                            PUT    directorycategories/:id(.:format)                                              backend/directorycategories#update
                                            DELETE directorycategories/:id(.:for
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If you could run 'rake routes' and post the output, that might be helpful)

Have you tried adding the module in your routes.rb? I think this may be close to the result you're looking for...

```
        resources :directorycategories, module: "backend" do
            resources :directorylistings
        end
```

Or you can specify the path directly...

```
resources :directorycategories, path: "/backend/directorycategories" do
            resources :directorylistings
        end
```

I'm fairly new to Rails so I'm not 100% but I don't know if your controllers need all of that extra code. (your controller file structure might provide a clearer picture of what you're trying to do)

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I accepted this as the right answer as this lead me down the right path. I did remove backend_ from most of the controllers except for redirect urls, I also left Backend:: part in to keep the namespace in the routes file.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that helped (somewhat at least). A great resource that I found really helpful [here](https://gorails.com/episodes/a-look-into-routing?autoplay=1)  - Its a free tutorial from GoRails.com They've really helped me with some of the slightly more advanced features I've tried.